# How to avoid detection of NFC tag in android?

Tags: android, nfc, android-pendingintent, android-intent-chooser

I am making an app with NFC. I want the detection is disabled or drops(no vibration, no sound, no app chooser dialog, no detection notification) in some activities or fragments.

Is that possible?

Only I did is using `SingleTop` in manifest and to the `Intent` like this:

In `Manifests.xml`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in the `MainActivity`

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)
```

Comment: Remove this `<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />` and try

Comment: @MD ???. Then I can't use NFC feature in the app at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because `default wallet`. Some devices can Choose NFC reader in the NFC setting. You need to turn it off. I never tried the solution that you detect notification and close it. There is `NotificationListenerService`. You gotta look into it if you want to disable all the notifications.